# How to change image path in WordPress to subdomain in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have one big site in WordPress that has many images. I want to speed up site using subdomain to browser load images from subdomain.

I want to point subdomain root to `wp-content/uploads/` and instead to load from:

`www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/example.jpg`

I want to load from:

`www.media.example.com/2015/03/example.jpg`

Where in PHP I can change that?

Comment: Yes! The same server as the domain

Comment: See this http://www.oxhow.com/host-images-wordpress-blog-subdomain-better-speed/

Comment: @Darian This is fantastic but I don't have that 2 fields in my dashboard. I can only setup image size but "Full url pat to files" and "Store uploads..." field I don't have. My Version is 4.2.2

Comment: There is an update on the article. Please review.

Comment: @Darian Yes I find now. Thanks!

Comment: @Darian Please write this in answer to I can give you vote and approve. This fix my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Actually I just gave you a link so I shouldn't be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need using PHP,

your just need to run this this SQL Query in phpmyadmin.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'http://www.yourdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/','http://images.yourdomain.com/')
```

For more information you can refer to this link.

http://www.oxhow.com/host-images-wordpress-blog-subdomain-better-speed/

Answer (score 1):

Go to *wp-admin/options.php*

There you have two options:

**upload_path**

**upload_url_path**

Change both and you're all set